# KVM: Machines unbootable after host reboot

Tags: kvm-virtualization, boot

Im finding that my KVM guests are unusable after i reboot my host.   Specifically, I always get this error:

> Booting from hard disk
>
> Boot failed: not a bootable disk

What causes this error?  I've tried toggling the VM disk type between qcow2 and raw, because a few articles online mentioned that this can happen if virt doesnt know the type of image to load, but that did not help.

** some more details **

I create My VMs from source using a command somewhat like this:

```
    base="http://mirror.pnl.gov/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/"
nohup sudo virt-install --hvm --name $vm_name$i --ram 4000 \
--disk path=/VirtualMachines/$vm_name$i,size=30 \
--location $base -x  "ks=http://xxx.os21.ks$kx"&
```

My virsh file looks like this:

```
      1 <domain type='kvm'>
  2   <name>testFriApr11092714EDT2014_1</name>
  3   <uuid>d4c86892-fb15-04ed-f4ab-7e3c76974ffc</uuid>
  4   <memory unit='KiB'>4096000</memory>
  5   <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4096000</currentMemory>
  6   <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  7   <os>
  8     <type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel6.4.0'>hvm</type>
  9     <boot dev='hd'/>
 10   </os>
 11   <features>
 12     <acpi/>
 13     <apic/>
 14     <pae/>
 15   </features>
 16   <clock offset='utc'/>
 17   <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
 18   <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
 19   <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
 20   <devices>
 21     <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
 22     <disk type='file' device='disk'>
 23       <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
 24       <source file='/VirtualMachines/testFriApr11092714EDT2014_1'/>
 25       <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
 26       <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
 27     </disk>
 28     <controller type='usb' index='0'>
 29       <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
 30     </controller>
 31     <controller type='ide' index='0'>
 32       <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
 33     </controller>
 34     <interface type='network'>
 35       <mac address='52:54:00:81:bd:fe'/>
 36       <source network='default'/>
```

Comment: What's in the libvirt log file for the VM?

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jayunit100/63fb07e35c128befc3be/raw/04260e2e15615a26217764a1b525a746e08a0472/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Wait...if you're using virt-install, you forgot any option to boot an installation!

Comment: can you clarify what you mean ? maybe there is an answer here?

Comment: You can't install a system without booting some kind of installation media. Whether it be a CDROM image or a standalone kernel/initrd, or whatever.

Comment: well, the VM certainly is "installed" at the beggining - it runs just fine.  but after host reboot, nothing works.  the VMs are still available it seems to virtual machine manager etc... but they dont boot up.  are you saying its not properly installing the boot drive?

Comment: any other thoughts?

Comment: How about http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/After_import_a_guest_from_an_existing_disk_image_using_virt-install,_the_guest_starting_stalls_with_%22No_boot_device%22 Change the disk bus type from ide to virtio.

Comment: yes i saw that one, no luck though

Comment: [Looks like this might help?](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/App_Domain_Not_Booting.html) EDIT: Nevermind, that's almost the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that the boot disk is not found or does not contain a valid boot sector.

- Are you writing the boot image on this disk during the OS install ?
- is the path specified in the VM file the correct disk image?

I think the problem may be the later, notice that you have:

`<source file='/VirtualMachines/testFriApr11092714EDT2014_1'/>`

- Is it possible that `/VirtualMachines/testFriApr11092714EDT2014_1` does not represent an existing file? ..
- Does an `ls -l /VirtualMachines/testFriApr11092714EDT2014_1` show that this file actually is there ?
- If the file is there, then KVM probably needs a file that ends in .img (for raw format) or .qcow2 (for qcow format).

Additional troubleshooting steps:

- attach a {CD,DVD}-ROM device (via virt-manager or virsh)
- enable boot-menu
- boot from CD/DVD when unable to boot, and actually look at the disk