# How does virt-install create and persist and secure the boot disk?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, boot

Normally when i run virt install, I boot initially from the network, by installing from source, and also including a "--disk" option.  The way i do it is described here ( in the "root" of this question which i dont have the answer to).

[KVM: Machines unbootable after host reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/589806/kvm-machines-unbootable-after-host-reboot)

So im facing an issue: My VMs dont boot after i reboot the host, and I beleive maybe it is because I dont **create a proper bootable disk** when i do the initial install.

*UPDATE*

Ive confirmed that i can reboot guests without restarting the host.  Thus, somewhere, something must be going wrong with my disks between host reboots.  but how could that be?

***That is, how is it that rebooting my HOST, results in a GUEST VM not recognizing its own boot disk anymore?***

Comment: Can you reboot the VMs *before* you reboot the host?

Comment: yes.  i can reboot the vm's even if i "force" them off.  this only is a problem when i shut the host down.

Comment: Have you verified the VM disk image before and after host reboot with a MD5 or SHA checksum? Obviously it shouldn't change, but this should confirm whether the problem is with the host or the guest. KVM supports non-persistent disk images, but you are rebooting the guest successfully. It almost seems that it's the host which is using non-persistent storage.

Comment: thats a great idea .  where could such non-persistent storage reside?

Comment: Disk image looks same.  Making some headway on this in libvirt-users mailing list FYI.    Could be related to missing the " biosboot --fstype=biosboot --size=1 " option .

Comment: I don't use those optiosn and create VMs in a similar way. The only difference is I use, and this *could* make a difference, `--os-type` (and I give my disk images an extension of `.img`.) Otherwise, my `virt-install` looks nearly identical. It's supposed to auto-detect `--os-type`, but if you've customized the installer, maybe it's having a hard time? Do you want to give it a shot?

Comment: thanks i will try that as well.  this takes a long time to test as you can imagine.